# How to recursively join all texts of all preceding siblings?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <a>
   first
   <b>x</b>
   <c>y</c>
  </a>
  <b>second</b>
  <bar>hey</bar>
</foo>
```

This is my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="/foo">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="bar" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="bar">
    [<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::text()"/>]
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm expecting this:

```
[first x y second]
```

However, it doesn't work as expected. Simply put, I'm interested to join all texts (recursively) of all siblings of the current node.

Comment: Your question is tagged `xsl-2.0` yet your stylesheet declares `version="1.0"`. There is a very big difference in how the `xsl:value-of` instruction will behave under the 2 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The siblings which you select are not themselves text nodes, therefore you cannot use the `text()` node test immediately after the `preceding-sibiling::` axis. Instead, you must select text *descendants* of these siblings.

You probably also want to omit whitespace-only texts such as the one between the `<b>` and `<c>` elements:

```xml
[<xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::*//text()
  [normalize-space(.)!='']"> <!-- filter out whitespace-only -->
  <xsl:if test="position()>1">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:for-each>]
```

If you want the texts separated by one space, you must insert that explicitly and remove trailing and leading whitespace with the `normalize-space` function.

(XSLT 1.0)

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0 you can do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/foo">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="bar" />
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="bar">
    <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::*//text()/normalize-space()"/>
    <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Read more about the `xsl:value-of` instruction here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#value-of.